# Counting number of letters in a string variable

Tags: c#, string

I'd like to count the number of letters in a string variable.

I want to make a Hangman game. I need to know how many letters are needed to match the number of letters in the word.

Comment: You want to count letters, or words?

Comment: You should post any code you've tried.

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: @crush Letters, sorry for the title.

Comment: Have you tried something along `str.Count(char.IsLetter)` ?

Comment: There's a lot missing from this question that leaves the answerer to assume.

Comment: Why not just retrieve the string, then replace all letters with an `_`, that way you'll have all the spaces and punctuation still there.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
myString.Length; //will get you your result
//alternatively, if you only want the count of letters:
myString.Count(char.IsLetter);
//however, if you want to display the words as ***_***** (where _ is a space)
//you can also use this:
//small note: that will fail with a repeated word, so check your repeats!
myString.Split(' ').ToDictionary(n => n, n => n.Length);
//or if you just want the strings and get the counts later:
myString.Split(' ');
//will not fail with repeats
//and neither will this, which will also get you the counts:
myString.Split(' ').Select(n => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(n, n.Length));
```

Comment: @walther OP didn't suggest that as part of his problem or solution. Are we to assume what his intended result is?

Comment: @walther: In the game of hangman, you want to count the spaces.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P: In the game of hangman you don't want to count the spaces. You want to handle each word separately leaving a space between the words. So: "my hangman question" => "__ _______ ________"

Comment: @MattRazza It depends. Anyways, I'm adding a solution for that.

Comment: @MattRazza: But you still need to know they exist, and where.

Comment: I'd probably just split to a list - dictionary seems like overkill for this. Length will still be a property of each element in the list.

Comment: @crush It depends, really.

Comment: of course, an array of strings is fine too...and more efficient.

Comment: `string yourWord = "Derp derp";`

`Console.WriteLine(new string(yourWord.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? '_' : c).ToArray()));`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use

```
int numberOfLetters = yourWord.Length;
```

or to be cool and trendy, use LINQ like this :

```
int numberOfLetters = yourWord.ToCharArray().Count();
```

and if you hate both Properties and LINQ, you can go old school with a loop :

```
int numberOfLetters = 0;
foreach (char letter in yourWord)
{
    numberOfLetters++;
}
```

Comment: Why not `yourWord.Length`? Probably want to strip the spaces too. Of course, he'll probably want to put actual spaces where those spaces go.

Comment: @crush because it's LINQ. `Length` is old school

Comment: Hahaha indeed, why did I have to make this so complex.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov But also more efficient...

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance He was being ironic :)

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance that was kind of sarcasm.. Sure `Length` is FAR more efficient in both speed and memory,  it's short and the list goes on...

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I don't think performance will really be an issue in calculating once a medium-sized word length.

Comment: Sorry, sarcasm is harder on the net :P

Comment: Hangman is hardly a processor intensive game.

Comment: If you really want to use the LINQ methods, there's no need to call `ToCharArray`. `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can write `yourWord.Count()`.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Indeed! That silly ReSharper forgot to tell me it was redundant to use ToCharArray.

Comment: guys, it's not only about performance, it's also about readability and intention-revealing code. Counting the length of a string with `ToCharArray().Count()` is like adding two numbers with `Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(2), Expression.Constant(3))).Compile()()` (it will return 5, just in case)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Okay, you might be taking it a little overboard now :P

Comment: @crush just look at his `foreach` loop at the end of the answer. `foreach` loop to count the number of characters in a string - that's a good solution for a successful interview...

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Wowzas. Talk about efficiency...

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with using `string.Length?`

```
// len will be 5
int len = "Hello".Length;
```

Comment: @Leigh - thanks for the catch, edited answer and will remove comment.

Comment: string.length gives the string length in bytes not characters.

Comment: @Nate this is quite old, but pretty sure still holds true. Are you talking about another lang perhaps?  Give it a shot and share result?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the leading and trailing spaces :

```
str.Trim().Length
```

Comment: That won't remove spaces...

Comment: `str.Replace(" ", "").Length;`

Comment: Also, `Length` is a property, not a method.

Comment: Isn't he counting the length of a single word? Well that's how I understood the question. My apologies.

Answer (score -2):

```
string yourWord = "Derp derp";

Console.WriteLine(new string(yourWord.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? '_' : c).ToArray()));
```

Yields:

`____ ____`